# RewriteCond if url is not "cdn.domain.com/images/"

Tags: .htaccess

we have created a CDN subdomain to host images, using this URL:

```
https://cdn.example.com/images/
```

What we want is to redirect, if someone goes to any other path of this subdomain. For example:

```
https://cdn.example.com/
https://cdn.example.com/blabla/
```

Redirect to other domain, just not redirect if the folder is `images`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following using mod_rewrite, near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^images/ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

If you access `cdn.example.com/<something>` and the URL-path does not start `/images/` then redirect to `https://example.com/<something>` (the main domain).

Change `R` to `R=301` (after you've made sure it is working OK) if you want a permanent redirect.

---

**UPDATE:** To exclude additional folders (eg. `images2` and `images3`) then you can change the `RewriteRule` directive to:

```
RewriteRule !^(images|images2|images3)/ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

If the folders are literally called `images`, `images2` and `images3` then this could be simplified to match (or rather *not* match) any URL of the form `/imagesN` - where `N` is an optional digit:

```
RewriteRule !^images\d?/ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: is not running, because when I access to:

cdn.example.com/blabla/ redirects to otherdomain.com
and I want to redirect to otherdomain.com/blabla/ (saving the path)

Comment: Thanks!! run ok :)

Comment: Please, can you let me to know how to add additional folders on the rewriterule? like images2, images3, etc...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

create htaccess file in your document root, and deny direct access to all files

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

and create htaccess file in `images`:

```
Allow from all
```

Comment: is not a option ,because both domains cdn.example.com and example.com are in the same virtualhost, your rules affect on both.